# Not getting result from cross database query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

**Both the collections are in different DB in local.**
try to fetch result but getting []. Please help

---

```
db.loans.aggregate([ 
{
    $lookup:{
        from: "payments",    
        localField: "ReferenceNumber", 
        foreignField: "LoanReferenceNumber",
        as: "pmt"   
    }
},

{
    $match:{
        $and:[{"ReferenceNumber" : "206344"}]
    }
},
{   
    $project:{
        _id : 0,
        ReferenceNumber : 1,
        Purpose : 1,
        AccountHolder : "$pmt.AccountHolder",
    } 
}
]);
```

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: This is not possible since [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database

Comment: is there a way that I can do it?

Comment: @onetwo12 , the posted query i use. I'm quite new to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to query using lookup in two different db's. [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in MongoDB supports Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database.

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

We can use getSibling("dbname") to query another db from one db

```
db.getSiblingDB('test').foo.find()
```

However, It is not possible to use sibling in aggregation.

Comment: can you suggest a way that I can get the desired result?